# How to run a function of an actual object, which is stored in the container using OOP?

Tags: c++

How to run a function of an actual object, which is stored in the container using OOP?

Background: I'm writing a game. There is a set of 4 interconnected rooms. There are two different room types and two different player types. Players should run as threads. The Killer should have a fight with a normal player in the Action room. In the second type of room, nothing should happen. The game logic and code is simplified.

When the thread starts, `void Player::operator()()` is being executed. The player enters the room, does his action `initializeAction()`, and leaves it. In case of a Killer, his `initializeAction()` leads to `room->actionInRoom(*this)`, which executes `player.inActionRoom()`.

The problem is in this code `void Killer::inActionRoom()`:

```
std::vector<Player> &playersWithoutKillers = room->getPlayersWithoutKillers();
auto it = playersWithoutKillers.begin();
std::advance(it, 0);
Player chosenPlayerForFight = *it;
...
chosenPlayerForFight.decreasePoints();
```

where `chosenPlayerForFight.decreasePoints();` does not decrease the points for the actual player, but I think it does it for a copy of an object.

If I run the code, this mistake is visible: OtherPlayer's points will always reset to 1. If I'm decreasing it every time the fight occurs, the negative value is expected.

```
-> Killer in Forth room Killer 11 vs OtherPlayer 1
Starting decreasing points from 1
Ending decreasing points from 0
```

I tried to fix the code, mainly by making sure the reference of an object is passed.

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include "Room.h"
#include "Player.h"

std::mutex globalMessageMutex;

int main() {

    auto first = std::make_shared<RelaxRoom>("First room");
    auto second = std::make_shared<ActionRoom>("Second room");
    auto third = std::make_shared<RelaxRoom>("Third room");
    auto forth = std::make_shared<ActionRoom>("Forth room");

    first->setRoomPair(second, forth);
    second->setRoomPair(third, first);
    third->setRoomPair(forth, second);
    forth->setRoomPair(first, third);

    std::vector<std::thread> players;

    players.emplace_back(OtherPlayer("OtherPlayer", first));
    players.emplace_back(Killer("Killer", first));

    for (auto &t : players) {
        if (t.joinable()) {
            t.join();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Player.h

```
#ifndef HW03_PLAYER_H
#define HW03_PLAYER_H

#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Room;

class Player {
    friend class Room;
public:
    Player(const std::string &playerName, std::shared_ptr<Room> initialTargetRoom);
    void operator()();
    friend bool operator== ( const Player &lhs, const Player &rhs );
    const std::string &getName() const;
    virtual void inActionRoom() {};
    virtual void inRelaxRoom(Room &pRoom) {};
    virtual bool isKiller()const;
    virtual bool isOtherPlayer();
    int getPoints()const;
    void increasePoints();
    void decreasePoints();
    int points;
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<Room> room;
    virtual void initializeAction();
private:
    std::string name;
    std::shared_ptr<Room> initialRoom;
};

class OtherPlayer : public Player {
public:
    OtherPlayer(const std::string &playerName, const std::shared_ptr<Room> &initialTargetRoom);
    void initializeAction() override;
    void inActionRoom() override;
    void inRelaxRoom(Room &pRoom) override;
    bool isOtherPlayer() override;
};


class Killer : public Player {
public:
    Killer(const std::string &playerName, const std::shared_ptr<Room> &initialTargetRoom);
    void initializeAction()  override;
    void inActionRoom() override;
    void inRelaxRoom(Room &pRoom) override;
    bool isKiller() const override;
};


#endif //HW03_PLAYER_H
```

Player.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <random>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Room.h"

extern std::mutex globalMessageMutex;

Player::Player(const std::string &playerName, std::shared_ptr<Room> initialTargetRoom) {
    name = playerName;
    initialRoom = initialTargetRoom;
    room = initialTargetRoom;
    points = 1;
}

void Player::operator()() {
    room->enter(*this);
    initializeAction();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
    room->leave(*this);

    while (auto nextRoom = room->getNext()) {
        room = nextRoom;
        nextRoom->enter(*this);
        initializeAction();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
        nextRoom->leave(*this);
    }
}

void Player::initializeAction() {}

bool operator==(const Player &lhs, const Player &rhs) {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name;
}

const std::string &Player::getName() const {
    return name;
}

bool Player::isKiller() const {
    return false;
}

bool Player::isOtherPlayer() {
    return false;
}

int Player::getPoints() const {
    return points;
}

void Player::increasePoints() {
    points++;
}

void Player::decreasePoints() {
    std::cout << "Starting decreasing points from " << points << std::endl;
    points--;
    std::cout << "Ending decreasing points from " << points << std::endl;
}


OtherPlayer::OtherPlayer(const std::string &playerName, const std::shared_ptr<Room> &initialTargetRoom) : Player(playerName,
                                                                                                         initialTargetRoom) {}

void OtherPlayer::initializeAction() {
    room->actionInRoom(*this);
}

void OtherPlayer::inActionRoom() {}

void OtherPlayer::inRelaxRoom(Room &pRoom) {}

bool OtherPlayer::isOtherPlayer() {
    return true;
}


Killer::Killer(const std::string &playerName, const std::shared_ptr<Room> &initialTargetRoom) : Player(playerName,
                                                                                                         initialTargetRoom) {}

void Killer::initializeAction() {
    room->actionInRoom(*this);
}

void Killer::inActionRoom() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> ml(globalMessageMutex);
    if (!room->getPlayersWithoutKillers().empty()) {

        **std::vector<Player> &playersWithoutKillers = room->getPlayersWithoutKillers();**

        **auto it = playersWithoutKillers.begin();
        std::advance(it, 0);
        Player chosenPlayerForFight = *it;**

        auto killersVitality = this->getPoints();
        auto othersPlayerPoints = chosenPlayerForFight.getPoints();

        std::cout << "-> Killer in " << room->getName() << " " << this->getName() << " " << killersVitality
                  << " vs " << chosenPlayerForFight.getName() << " " << othersPlayerPoints << std::endl;

        this->increasePoints();
        **chosenPlayerForFight.decreasePoints();**
    }
}

void Killer::inRelaxRoom(Room &pRoom) {

}

bool Killer::isKiller() const {
    return true;
}
```

Room.h

```
#ifndef HW03_ROOM_H
#define HW03_ROOM_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <condition_variable>


class Player;
class Room {

public:
    Room(const std::string &roomName);
    void setRoomPair(std::shared_ptr<Room> firstRoom, std::shared_ptr<Room> secondRoom);
    std::shared_ptr<Room> getNext();
    void enter(Player &player);
    void leave(Player &player);
    virtual void actionInRoom(Player &player)= 0;
    const std::string &getName() const;
    const std::vector<Player> &getPlayers();
    std::vector<Player> &getPlayersWithoutKillers();

protected:
    std::string name;
    size_t killersCount;
    size_t playersWithoutKillersCount;

private:
    std::vector<Player> players;
    std::vector<Player> playersWithoutKillers;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::pair<std::shared_ptr<Room>, std::shared_ptr<Room>> roomPair;
    void updateCounterPlayerLeaves(Player &player);
    void updateCounterPlayerEnters(Player &player);
};

class ActionRoom : public Room {
public:
    ActionRoom(const std::string &roomName) : Room(roomName) {}
    void actionInRoom(Player &player) override;
};

class RelaxRoom : public Room {
public:
    RelaxRoom(const std::string &roomName) : Room(roomName) {}
    void actionInRoom(Player &player) override;
};

#endif //HW03_ROOM_H
```

Room.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include "Room.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include <mutex>

extern std::mutex globalMessageMutex;


Room::Room(const std::string &roomName) {
    name = roomName;
}

const std::string &Room::getName() const {
    return name;
}

std::shared_ptr<Room> Room::getNext() {
    auto seed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::mt19937 engine(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> randomGenerator(0, 1);
    auto randomNumber = randomGenerator(engine);
    if (randomNumber) {
        return roomPair.second;
    }
    return roomPair.first;
}

void Room::enter(Player &player) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    cv.wait(lock, [this, &player] {
                return true;
            }
    );

    players.push_back(player);

    updateCounterPlayerEnters(player);

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> ml(globalMessageMutex);
    std::cout << name << ": killers: " << killersCount << ", other players: " << playersWithoutKillersCount <<
              std::endl;
}

void Room::updateCounterPlayerEnters(Player &player) {
    if (player.isKiller()) {
        killersCount++;
    } else {
        playersWithoutKillersCount++;
        playersWithoutKillers.push_back(player);
    }
}

void Room::leave(Player &player) {
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        auto it = std::find(players.begin(), players.end(), player);
        if (it == players.end()) {
            return;
        }
        players.erase(it);

        updateCounterPlayerLeaves(player);
    }

    cv.notify_all();
}

void Room::updateCounterPlayerLeaves(Player &player) {
    if (player.isKiller()) {
        killersCount--;
    } else {
        playersWithoutKillersCount--;
        auto it = std::find(playersWithoutKillers.begin(), playersWithoutKillers.end(), player);
        if (it == playersWithoutKillers.end()) {
            return;
        }
        playersWithoutKillers.erase(it);
    }
}

void Room::setRoomPair(std::shared_ptr<Room> firstRoom, std::shared_ptr<Room> secondRoom) {
    roomPair.first = std::move(firstRoom);
    roomPair.second = std::move(secondRoom);
}

const std::vector<Player> &Room::getPlayers() {
    return players;
}

std::vector<Player> &Room::getPlayersWithoutKillers() {
    return playersWithoutKillers;
}

void ActionRoom::actionInRoom(Player &player) {
    player.inActionRoom();
}

void RelaxRoom::actionInRoom(Player &player) {
    player.inRelaxRoom(*this);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why complicate something like this with threads? Would be much less error prone as a single threaded state machine. IMHO.

Comment: Jesper Juhl, threads are the requirement of an assignment

Comment: Change it to `Player &chosenPlayerForFight = *it;` you create a copy right there

Comment: Slava, unfortunately, it does not help.

Comment: If you want OOP you store **pointers** in your container. You can use smart pointers but you cannot use actual objects.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, since you said this is a homework assignment.

However, one pattern you can use to solve this problem is to have your container store `std::unique_ptr<some_base_class>` values, or if necessary `std::shared_ptr<some_base_class>`, and fill them with pointers to derived objects. For example: `container.emplace_back(static_cast<some_base_class*>(new derived_class(foo, bar, baz)));` will construct everything in place inside your container, so the compiler doesn’t need to make any temporary copies.  You might also write something like:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<some_base_class>> container;

{
   std::unique_ptr<derived_class> temp =
     make_unique<derived_class>();
   temp->setup( foo, bar, baz );
   container.emplace_back(static_cast<some_base_class*>(temp.release()));
   // temp is now empty, and the pointer in the container now owns the object.
}
```

You can use the full interface of `some_base_class` through these smart pointers, with `->`, but if you need to turn them back into references to derived objects, you would use RTTI and `dynamic_cast`.

There are other approaches, including a discriminated union and `std::variant`, but storing smart pointers to the base class that defines your interface is what I recommend you try here.

Comment: If I understand right the smart pointers should be created in the main method:
`std::shared_ptr<Killer> player1 = std::make_shared<Killer>(...); players.emplace_back(*player1.get());`
But I need them actually in the `Player` class itself, where they are pointing to, so that in `operator()()` I could pass a smart pointer instead of `*this` etc. I tried `shared_from_this`, but it didn’t work (`std::bad_weak_ptr`) or worked but did not offer Killer subclass polymorphic behavior `std::shared_ptr<Player> player1 = std::make_shared<Killer>(...)`

Comment: @GeorgeP. Could you store shared pointers in `players`, and then dereference them? So, `*players[0]()` or `players[0]->get()`? To get polymorphic behavior of a derived class at runtime, the method must be `virtual`, which is the case here, and called through a pointer to the base class.

Comment: @GeorgeP. To cast a `shared_ptr<Player>` back to a `killer&`, you would either check `is_killer()` or check the `typeid`, then `dynamic_cast` the contents of the smart pointer to `killer&`. But avoid this if possible and use polymorphism.

Comment: @GeorgeP. Creating the pointers and transferring ownership of them to the container item is a good idea!

Comment: @GeorgeP. Rewrote the example code so that a smart pointer to the derived class is created and then ownership is transferred to the base-class smart pointer in the container.