# Is it possible to create a smart pointer to an object and pass this smart pointer as an argument to the constructor?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to create a smart pointer to an object and pass this smart pointer as an argument to the constructor? I would like to use a smart pointer to the object in the object itself.

```
auto player1 = std::make_shared<Player>(argument1, ..smartpointer_to_player1..);
```

Comment: urrrr... But why?

Answer (score 3):

If you want a class to have a `shared_ptr` to itself (or, rather, its `this` pointer), there is an alternative way to accomplish this instead of your proposed solution via `std::enable_shared_from_this`. For example:

```
class Player : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Player> {

//... definition

   std::shared_ptr<Player> GetPtr() { return shared_from_this(); }
};
```

By inheriting this class, it allows you to get a `shared_ptr` to the `this` pointer by calling the inherited member function `shared_from_this` in any of the class' member functions (although this function would not be available in the constructor). One limitation of this is that the object would need to have been stored in a `shared_ptr` previously or this will caused undefined behavior (before C++17) or throw `std::bad_weak_ptr` (C++17 and after).

In any case, this will likely give you the functionality you would like and avoid having to pass a `shared_ptr` to itself via the constructor.

Comment: Beware that `shared_from_this()` isn't available in the constructor. This seems like it solves OP's problem, but the question does mention the constructor a few times.

Comment: Using `shared_from_this` on an instance that isn't managed by a `shared_ptr` is only undefined behavior until c++17. In c++17 and later it throws [`std::bad_weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/bad_weak_ptr).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not get it to work. If I create a shared pointer `std::shared_ptr<Subplayer> player2 = std::make_shared<Subplayer>();` the polymorphic behavior is correct, but if I try to get a pointer I get an error `std::bad_weak_ptr`. If I create it this way: `std::shared_ptr<Player> player2 = std::make_shared<Subplayer>();`, then there is no error, but there is no polymorphic behavior either (the overridden functions for Subplayer are not being used, Subplayer is a subclass)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you're right about the constructor and the thrown exception c++17 and after. I was still thinking in c++14 rules :)

Comment: @GeorgeP. I'm not sure I follow, and I would need to see some code to see what you are doing (possibly in a new question)

Comment: @Daniel, the code and the initial problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257337/how-to-run-a-function-of-an-actual-object-which-is-stored-in-the-container-usin

Answer (score 1):

If the object needs a shared pointer to itself it should inherit from [std::enable_shared_from_this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) and then obtain the shared pointer by calling [shared_from_this()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) in the member function where it needs it.

Comment: You cannot use `shared_from_this` in the object's constructor. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924396/why-shared-from-this-cant-be-used-in-constructor-from-technical-standpoint).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not get it to work. If I create a shared pointer `std::shared_ptr<Subplayer> player2 = std::make_shared<Subplayer>();` the polymorphic behavior is correct, but if I try to get a pointer I get an error `std::bad_weak_ptr`. If I create it this way: `std::shared_ptr<Player> player2 = std::make_shared<Subplayer>();`, then there is no error, but there is no polymorphic behavior either (the overridden functions for Subplayer(subclass) are not being used). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257337/how-to-run-a-function-of-an-actual-object-which-is-stored-in-the-container-usin